# Caching setup steps such as installing PHP when using Github Actions

Tags: github-actions

I've got a workflow that has some setup steps that install php with a bunch of extensions & composer.

Is it possible to cache the `Install PHP` and `Install Composer & Dependencies` so these steps don't have to happen on every run?

These steps combined take about 4 mins of a 5 min run.

```
name: Build
on:
  workflow_call:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          path: ./src

      - name: Install PHP
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update -y  && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true
          echo "tzdata tzdata/Areas select Europe" >> /tmp/preseed.cfg
          echo "tzdata tzdata/Zones/Europe select Berlin" >> /tmp/preseed.cfg
          sudo apt install software-properties-common -y
          sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
          sudo apt update
          sudo apt-get install php8.1 -y --quiet
          sudo apt-get install php8.1-dev libmcrypt-dev php-pear php-xml php8.1-xml -y
          sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
          sudo apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-php8.1 php8.1-common php8.1-gmp php8.1-curl php8.1-soap php8.1-bcmath php8.1-intl php8.1-mbstring php8.1-xmlrpc php8.1-mysql php8.1-gd php8.1-xml php8.1-cli php8.1-zip
          sudo rm /usr/bin/php; sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/php8.1 /usr/bin/php

      - name: Install Composer & Dependencies
        run: |
          cd ./src/ || exit 99
          sudo apt-get install -y git zip libzip-dev openssh-client libmcrypt-dev
          sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          cp auth.json.pipeline auth.json
          sudo composer self-update --2
          composer install --no-dev --verbose --prefer-dist --no-ansi --no-interaction
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using [Setup PHP](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-php-action) and [Install PHP Dependencies with Composer](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/install-php-dependencies-with-composer) GitHub Actions instead of manually installing PHP and Composer with dependencies.

These actions already have a caching mechanism and provide many interesting and valuable things additionally.

**For example:**

```
name: PHP
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - uses: 'shivammathur/setup-php@v2'
        name: Setup PHP
        with:
          php-version: '8.1'

      - uses: 'ramsey/composer-install@v2'
        name: Install Composer & Dependencies

      - name: Run Script
        run: |
          php -v
          composer -v
```

Running this WF on my little test PHP project with few dependencies takes about 30s without cache and 20s when cache exists.

Execution demo: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XenUD.png).

Cache demo: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr2yY.png).

In addition, there is a [Cache](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/cache) GitHub action that can be used if you need manually cache some things for your workflow.

[Learn more about managing caches](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows#managing-caches).